# How make view with two models using simple_form gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I have two models. User have_many articles. How can I make one view for this models with simple_form gem? I can't find this part in wiki and readme :(

For example, something like "simple_form_for [ user, articles ] do |f|"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `simple_fields_for` method to create sub-forms for your main model's associations.

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>

  <%= simple_fields_for :articles do |article_form| %>
    <%= article_form.input :title %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Also, don't forget to tell your model to accept nested attributes, or the record will be invalid.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :articles 

  attr_accessible :articles_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles 
end
```